# How to set color and width of plotted ROI slice using PyQtGraph

Tags: pyqtgraph

When I plot 2D image with `pg.image(my_image)` I often need to see 1D slice of the image. I use ROI button to do this but default color and line width of plotted slice are not suitable for me. How to change them?

Answer (score 0):

How are you making the plot? `PlotDataItem` and `PlotCurveItem` classes both allow you to set the pen used when drawing. See:

http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotdataitem.html#pyqtgraph.PlotDataItem.setPen
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpen.html

Comment: I don't make my plot. I use `pg.image(my_2D_image)` and I want to know how to set color of plot which appears at the bottom when I press ROI button on the widget. I don't know how to get `PlotDataItem` and `PlotCurveItem` classes from `pg.image()`.